# How to view or print data from CNTK C# Value object

Tags: c#, cntk

How can I see the data from xVals in debug mode or by printing it to console; from the statement:

```
var xVals = Value.CreateSequence<float>(new int[] { 2 }, new float[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }, DeviceDescriptor.CPUDevice);
```

I want know how the data is reshaped by this function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    IList<IList<float>> data = xVals.GetDenseData<float>(Variable.InputVariable(new int[] { 2, 3 }, DataType.Float);
```

The Variable.InputVariable is needed for its shape information so it shall has the same shape as the Value you created.

Comment: There is no shape information in the variable 'data'. It is displaying the same data that is fed to it.  I wanted to see how my data is being reshaped when I create a value object using CreateSequence.